# Is there a way to check if I'm inside a servlet request with Guice?

Tags: java, servlets, guice, guice-servlet

I'm writing a JUL logging `Handler` and I'd like to augment the logged messages with information about the current request, if we're currently handling a request.  To accomplish this, I've injected a `Provider<Thing>` into the `Handler`, where `Thing` is `@RequestScoped`.

However, calling `provider.get()` throws an `OutOfScopeException` if the logging happens while we're not handling a request.  I feel like catching the `OutOfScopeException` would be bad form.  Is there a better way to determine whether or not a request is currently executing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With wicket I used a little trick. This should be framework independent. I made a request filter and put a public static ThreadLocal in it. So if current thread is born from request, threadlocal will be set.

```
public class SessionContext implements Filter {

    private static final ThreadLocal<HttpSession> session = new ThreadLocal<HttpSession>();

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
        return;
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        session.set(((HttpServletRequest)servletRequest).getSession());
        filterChain.doFilter(servletRequest, servletResponse);
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
        return;
    }

    public static HttpSession getSession(){
        return session.get();
    }

    public static User getUser(){
        return (User) session.get().getAttribute(UserService.USER);
    }
}
```

and in web.xml:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>session</filter-name>
    <filter-class>SessionContext</filter-class>
</filter>
```

Comment: That's a good idea!  In fact, you don't even have to mess with web.xml, you can use the `filter("/*").through(MyFilter.class)` syntax: https://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/ServletModule#Filter_Mapping

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is no elegant way to do this. The Guice API is tight and will not grant access to the thread-local needed to make such a test. As of version 3, the thread-local in question sits on `com.google.inject.servlet.GuiceFilter#localContext`. You could access it by reflection but it is arguably even worse style than catching the exception.

I would stick on caching the exception... or hack into that class and add an static boolean test method.

Comment: Yeah I looked at the code in GuiceFilter and ServletScopes and figured I couldn't use them for the check.  There's no built-in Guice way to check if the caller is inside a scope?  If not I guess I'll just make my own ThreadLocal.